# Variable scoping of edef definitions in a local group (inside an ifx conditional)?

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals, scoping

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\testswitch#1{
  \def\isA{A}
  \def\firstOpt{#1}
  \edef\tmpstr{-init-}
  { % start local
    \edef\tmpstr{-loc defined-}
  } % end local
  \ifx\firstOpt\isA{%
    \typeout{testswitch: Condition A is true; '#1'}
    \edef\tmpstr{yes, it is}
  }\else{
    \typeout{testswitch: Condition false ; '#1'}
    \edef\tmpstr{no it is not}
  }\fi
  \typeout{testswitch: completed, tmpstr is '\tmpstr'}
}

\def\testswitcher#1{
  \begingroup
  \testswitch{#1}
  \typeout{testswitcher: completed, tmpstr is '\tmpstr'}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\def\tmpstr{-master start-}
\testswitcher{A}
\typeout{after testswitcher, tmpstr: '\tmpstr'}
\testswitcher{B}
\typeout{after testswitcher, tmpstr: '\tmpstr'}

\end{document}
```

It outputs:

```
testswitch: Condition A is true; 'A'
testswitch: completed, tmpstr is '-init-'
testswitcher: completed, tmpstr is '-init-'
after testswitcher, tmpstr: '-master start-'
testswitch: Condition false ; 'B'
testswitch: completed, tmpstr is '-init-'
testswitcher: completed, tmpstr is '-init-'
after testswitcher, tmpstr: '-master start-'
```

Basically, when \tmpstr is defined in either any local group - including those that appear in course of usage of the `\ifx` conditional (since, as I remember, `{` and `}` are synonyms for `\bgroup` and `\egroup`) - then it will not have any effect outside of the local group; therefore we always print out the '-init-' value.

I'm aware that I can use a `\global\edef` (`\xdef`) or a variant (`\global\let\tmpstr\tmpstr`) inside local group, to have the value preserved - but then, it becomes a global variable - and in this case, I don't want that; I would just want the `\edef`'d token to survive within the context where it is used - in this MWE, that is the `\testswitcher` macro; I would basically want this output:

```
testswitch: Condition A is true; 'A'
testswitch: completed, tmpstr is 'yes, it is'
testswitcher: completed, tmpstr is 'yes, it is'
after testswitcher, tmpstr: '-master start-'
```

Can I control this level of variable scoping in Latex - and if so, how?

Comment: `\ifx` does not use any grouping, do you need the grouping for some other reason? if not just use `\ifx\a\b  xx \else yy\fi` not  `\ifx\a\b  {xx} \else{ yy}\fi`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - thanks for that, I had no idea! `:)` I always sort of thought that the `{}` braces were required (in the same sense they are syntactically required in `C`); it didn't occur to me that they were an addition to keep a change local (as my knowledge o the `{ == \bgroup` should have pointed to)! Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Also, why `\edef` here not just `\def`: you've got no expandable tokens.

Comment: @sdaau It's the other way around: `\bgroup` = `{` (as TeX is catcode based, it's the fact that `{` has catcode 1 that's important).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @JosephWright - `\edef` was just an artefact in copying from the original code which caused me problems, and that forced me to make this MWE; sorry about that - thanks for the correction, too. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau You can even do `\ifx\a\b{\else}\fi` (if you know what you're doing); this will contribute an open brace if the conditional returns true, a closed brace otherwise. The LaTeX kernel is full of strange things like ``\ifnum0=`{\fi}`` that will contribute just a closed brace but can go in the body of a definition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @egreg - that with the conditional "contributing a brace" is one of those things that I _always_ find confusing; great to have a reference here - cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is

```
\ifx\a\b
 stuff
\else
other stuff
\fi
```

and no grouping is implied. By going

```
\ifx\a\b{
 stuff
}\else{
other stuff
}\fi
```

You were keping both branches in local groups.

Note also that you are missing lots of `%` from ends of lines if you do not want to introduce white space into the output.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @DavidCarlisle - given how I forget things like this, it will be great as a reference. Cheers!